# ros.spinOnce() during delay

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Say I have a ros rate of 10 Hz. Does `ros.spinOnce()` occur during `ros::Duration(2).sleep()` ?

Example:

```
void main(void){
  ros::nh;
  ros::rate r(10);
  while(ros::ok())
  {
    do something;

    ros::Duration(2).sleep();
    ros::spinOnce();
  }
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253754/ros.spinonce()-during-delay/) by [roborag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29131/roborag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-02-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [afakih](https://answers.ros.org/users/24990/afakih/) on 2017-02-08**:
`ros::rate r(10);` as it is used, is doing nothing. If you want the loop to run at 10Hz you should call `r.sleep()` at the end of your while loop.

Currently the loop would run at a rate of 1/(2 + call backs processing time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This has been asked before. See #q203760.

And we could also look at the source: [ros::Duration::sleep()](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/111977aa7869ad7e9381e7ea94c815ed4b285742/rostime/src/time.cpp#L392-L430) eventually calls [ros_wallsleep(..)](https://github.com/ros/roscpp_core/blob/111977aa7869ad7e9381e7ea94c815ed4b285742/rostime/src/time.cpp#L209-L222), which basically does:

```
timespec req = { sec, nsec };
timespec rem = {0, 0};
while (nanosleep(&req, &rem) && !g_stopped)
{
  req = rem;
}
```

and nothing more.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0